# Homebrew putty installation does not make the putty command recognisable

Tags: terminal, install, homebrew, package-management

I would like to instal [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) with use of Homebrew. I'm performing the following command:

```
brew install putty
```

which gives the seemingly correct output:

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/putty-0.67.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/thisuser/Library/Caches/Homebrew/putty-0.67.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring putty-0.67.el_capitan.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/putty/0.67: 11 files, 1.5M
```

However, the `putty` command is not recognised:

```
thisuser-541/41:~$ putty
-bash: putty: command not found
```

Comment: is there a putty in /usr/local/bin

Comment: Is it possible that you did not add /usr/local/bin to your PATH variable? Execute `echo $PATH` and post the output here.

Comment: The `/usr/local/bin` is in the `$PATH`. For some reason `putty` is not, only `puttygen`.

Comment: check this folder /usr/local/Cellar/putty/0.63/bin/ there might be no putty in there, but as you said there may be puttygen.

Comment: Very frustrating. Screen crashes whenever a USB-UART device disconnects - which, during hardware debugging is fairly frequent. As a bonus, it often leaves a terminal unusable (`stty sane` sometimes recovers).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Update:** Current stable version (`.67`) of `putty` can't be build with `gtk+2` support on OS X using homebrew. This is a know issue [#40951](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/40951). It seems you can install from `HEAD` version (`brew install --HEAD --with-gtk+3 putty`) and for me that is also broken.

`brew install putty` by default installs from a pre-built `bottle`. The pre-built `bottle` for `putty` doesn't include `putty`, `puttytel` or `pterm`.

If you want `putty` then can try installing from source. First remove the installed `putty` formula by running `brew remove putty`. After that install `putty` from source by running `brew install --build-from-source --with-gtk+3 putty`.

**NOTE:** *As of this writing building `putty` from source is broken with `homebrew`*

If someone is getting an error like this: `invalid option: --with-gtk+3`, all installation options are removed with the latest version of the brew. [source](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/31510)

Comment: if it helps - the source of [putty formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/putty.rb)

Comment: removed putty, did the brew install --build-from-source --with-gtk+3 putty, all appears to install normal. But still no putty app. What am I missing? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-gtk+3

Comment: @aeroxy try to install gtk3 first then try it again.
`brew install gtk+3`

Comment: execute: brew install gtk+3 , but try to execute brew install --build-from-source --with-gtk+3 putty and returned error Error: invalid option: --with-gtk+3

Answer (score 1):

On Catalina the putty formula only installs 4 helper tools and not the application.

```
MD5 (plink) = d16fd757c526aa77f760f6e1f3a2cd50
MD5 (pscp) = cbae18d5ca00b3f43db502d4c826316a
MD5 (psftp) = b1568055518b21e9612984558ca7192f
MD5 (puttygen) = 9001883be59e4956e06bb1eaa8f189bd
```

You probably want to use `screen` and `scp` / `ssh` over putty unless you have a very specific need. In this question, there's no explanation of what putty will do, so feel free to ask a follow on question explaining [how you intend to use putty on Catalina](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284960/installing-putty-on-osx) and link here if you think I could be of use in answering a related question.

When I say "on Catalina" I'm referring to this build:

```
mike@me bin % brew info putty
putty: stable 0.73 (bottled), HEAD
Implementation of Telnet and SSH
https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/
Conflicts with:
  pssh (because both install `pscp` binaries)
/usr/local/Cellar/putty/0.73 (12 files, 1.9MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2020-05-16 at 07:11:14
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/putty.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 8,542 (30 days), 26,477 (90 days), 105,520 (365 days)
install-on-request: 8,442 (30 days), 26,142 (90 days), 103,075 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

Answer (score -3):

Putty can be installed with three easy steps:

```
1. First Open the terminal
2. Install the homebrew
3. Run command "brew install putty"
```

You can get the detailed steps at [BrewInstall](https://brewinstall.org/Install-putty-on-Mac-with-Brew/)
Search for any mac app or packages here and get steps to install it.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem raised in the question. Also, this basically is a link-only answer. Please include the relevant parts directly in your post so people don't need to follow a link to find the solution.

Comment: After you run these steps - how does `putty` run? This is not a helpful answer unless I have missed something essential when I answered. Am I out of date and this package has anything except 4 helpers since May?