# Brew Install PuTTY appears to install but putty command not found

Tags: terminal, homebrew, ssh

Relatively new to the Mac world but this seems weird. Installing PuTTY with Homebrew and appears to install fine.

`brew install --build-from-source putty`

Following output...

```
==> Downloading https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.76/putty-0.76.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./configure --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/putty/0.76 --libdir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/putty/0.76/lib --di
==> make VER=-DRELEASE=0.76
  /opt/homebrew/Cellar/putty/0.76: 14 files, 2.2MB, built in 10 seconds
==> Running `brew cleanup putty`...
Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).

macbookuser@macbook ~ % putty
zsh: command not found: putty
```

I've searched around and haven't found an acceptable solution.

[Old reference to the same issue found here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240679/homebrew-putty-installation-does-not-make-the-putty-command-recognisable)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. If I find the solution soon then will update for anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: Is this the first command you installed via Homebrew?

Comment: Coming at this from a different angle - are you sure you actually need Putty? - There are many other programs available on macOS that serve the same purpose as various parts of Putty - and some of them are even built-in to macOS in a default install.

Comment: Given the link isn't this a problem with putty itself and so should be on their bug list?

Comment: Unless something has changed, `putty` on macOS requires X11.  So what parts of it is Homebrew actually installing?  The linked answer seems to make it plain that the only things Homebrew installs are the helper tools.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish using putty on macos?
You're better off using iTerm2, Hyper, Alacritty, Kitty, Tabby (All GUI based terminal alternatives.)

If you're trying to establish a serial connection to something; it's a bit more complicated since we're gonna have to switch out some permissions in order to get `screen` running  (if that's the case, there's a GUI alternative called Serial [but it'll also require changes in regards to system permissions for running tftp or whatever it is you're trying to do ... if you could be more specific it'd be easier to help out. ])

also, if you really wanna stick to putty. I guess there's probably a putty GUI; -- try this:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask
brew search putty
```

if you find anything;

```
brew install --cask putty
```

Permission or checksum (sha verification issues) can be handled by issuing

```
export HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS=" "

source ~/.{shell}rc

or simple

HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS=" "

reload the shell and try again
```